# how to not print the index url in generated requirements.txt when using piptools

Tags: python, pip

I am using `piptools` to compile `requirements.in` to generate `requirements.txt`.

I also have some index url written in my `.pip/pip.conf` file which I store my credentials to our python artifactory repo. So whenever I do `pip-compile requirements.in` the generated `requirements.txt` will contain a line reflecting that index url such as the following. I don't want this line to be there, is there a configuration where we can configure `pip-tools` to not generate this line to `requirements.txt`?

```
--extra-index-url https://pli:credentials@mydomain.jfrog.io/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add the `--no-emit-index-url` flag to the pip-compile command, or `--no-index` for pre-`5.2.0` versions.

EDIT: Official docs for this flag are [here](https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/pip-compile/#pip-compile).